# firebase build is not coming through. Or axios is called before firebase authentication is complete

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, axios

I am developing using typescript,react,next.js,firebase.
The code in (1) was used at first. However, when initially drawing, I get a 401 error in apiClient.interceptors.response. The cause was that Axios was called before Firebase authentication was completed.
Therefore, I changed the code from (1) to (2). The waitForFirebaseAuth in code ② is a function that waits for Firebase authentication to complete.
After changing the code to ②, the error 401 in apiClient.interceptors.response. at the time of initial rendering was fixed. However, when I pass the build through npm run build, error (3) occurs. I have no idea how to solve this problem.
I would like someone to tell me how to solve this problem.

version
"firebase": "^10.0.0",
"@firebase/auth": "^1.2.0",
"next": "^13.4.7",
"axios": "^1.5.0",

```
①
import Axios from 'axios';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

export const apiClient = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 30000,
});

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    let token = '';

    if (user) {
      token = await user.getIdToken();
    }

    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

```
②
import Axios from 'axios';
import { getAuth, User } from 'firebase/auth';

export const apiClient = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 30000,
});

async function waitForFirebaseAuth() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  return new Promise<User | null>((resolve) => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    });
  });
}

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const user = await waitForFirebaseAuth();
    let token = '';

    if (user) {
      token = await user.getIdToken();
    }

    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

```
③
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
```

```
import { getApp, getApps, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUTH_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUTH_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUTH_PROJECT_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAUTH_APP_ID,
};

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && getApps().length === 0) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
export const auth = getAuth(getApp());
```

What I have tried is the code in (2) listed above